# [PowerShell]Get-Content and Add Column Entry?

Tags: powershell

I am trying to input a list of users into PowerShell and get a specific security group attached to the user's account. At this current time, I have two pieces - an Excel sheet with multiple pieces of data, and a .txt with just the user's usernames. The script I have currently just inputs the user's usernames from the .txt and gets the security group from their account that matches a specific prefix, however I noticed doing it this way doesn't give any specific order. Even though the users are in a specific order (copied and pasted exactly from the excel document), the actual output doesn't come back well.

So, here's what I'd Like to do now, I just don't know how. I would like to get the content from the Excel document, take all of the usernames and do Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership like I am now, and then write the security group Back to the line that matches the username. For example, if I looked up the SG for msnow, it would get the SG for msnow and then write the SG back to the row that has msnow, and continues through the list. Instead of just doing an Out-GridView, it would actually write this to the Excel document.

Any help on making this work?

Here is the code I have right now.

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

$Names = Get-Content C:\Temp\Users.txt
$Records = @()

Foreach ($ADUsers in $Names) {
    Try {
        $SG = Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $ADUsers | Select Name | Where {$_.Name -Like "SG - *"}
        $SGName = $SG.Name
    }
    Catch [ADIdentityNotFoundException] {
        $SGName = "User not found"
    }
    $Records += New-Object PSObject -Property @{"UserName" = $ADUsers;"Security Group" = $SGName}
}

Write-Host "Generating CSV File..."
$Records | Out-GridView
```

Thank you!

Comment: Reading from, doing stuff in between and writing back to Excel is really tiresome.. Why not save the Excel as CSV, read and manipulate that to create a new updated CSV file which you can simply open in Excel? [2] `Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership` can return multiple groups, do you want all group names to fit in the same cell?

Comment: A CSV would work too. I just want to make sure I get the code right to do it. And yeah, multiple SGs into the same cell would be fine IMO. I think there will definitely be cases where that happens, too.

Answer (score 0):

If you save the Excel as CSV, so it will look something like

```
"UserName","Security Group","InsideInfo"
"bloggsj","","tall guy"
"ftastic","","nothing worth mentioning"
```

things shouldn't be that hard to do.

```
$out = 'D:\Test\Updated_usersandgroups.csv'
$csv = Import-Csv -Path 'D:\Test\usersandgroups.csv'

Write-Host "Updating CSV File..."
foreach ($user in $csv) {
    try {
        $SG = Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $user.UserName -ErrorAction Stop
        # if more groups are returned, combine them into a delimited string
        # I'm using ', ' here, but you can change that to something else of course
        $SGName = ($SG | Where-Object {$_.Name -Like "SG - *"}).Name -join ', '
    }
    catch [ADIdentityNotFoundException] {
        $SGName = "User $($user.UserName) not found"
    }
    catch {
        # something else went wrong?
        $SGName = $_.Exception.Message
    }
    # update the 'Security Group' value
    $user.'Security Group' = $SGName
}

Write-Host "Generating updated CSV File..."
$csv | Export-Csv -Path $out -UseCulture -NoTypeInformation

# show output on screen
$csv | Format-Table -AutoSize  # or -Wrap if there is a lot of data

# show as GridView (sorts by column)
$csv | Out-GridView
```

Output in console would then look like

```
UserName Security Group           InsideInfo              
-------- --------------           ----------              
bloggsj  SG - Group1, SG - Group1 tall guy                
ftastic  SG - Group1              nothing worth mentioning
```

Note: I don't know what delimiter your Excel uses when saving to CSV file. On my Dutch machine, it uses the semi-colon `;`, so if in your case this is not a comma, add the delimiter character as parameter to the `Import-Csv` cmdlet: `-Delimiter ';'`

<sup>Excel uses whatever is set in your locale as ListSeparator for the delimiter character. In PowerShell you can see what that is by doing `(Get-Culture).TextInfo.ListSeparator`. On output, the `-UseCulture` switch will make sure it uses that delimiter so Excel will understand</sup>